# RRAS L2TP VPN DNS Issue on iDevices - No Internet

Tags: domain-name-system, rras, l2tp

I've setup an L2TP VPN server on Windows Server 2012 using RRAS and NPS primarily for connections from iPhone/iPad clients etc, the problem is I can't get internet connectivity to work when connected on the iPhone / iPad, whereas it does work when connected on my Windows 7 laptop - the laptop is configured to 'Use default gateway on remote network' and I've proved this by going to whatsmyip.com in a browser and proving that I get the public IP of the VPN server.

I've tried running Fing on the iPhone when connected to the VPN and I can ping external addresses but can't resolve external host names, so strongly sounds like a DNS issue. I've tried playing with the 'Send All Traffic' iOS VPN setting but this makes no difference. I'm confused why I'm getting internet on my laptop but not iPhone.

Important note, this is running on a windows server that's (amongst other things) promoted as a DC with a single NIC and DNS server role installed - it's a personal VPS that I'm renting for dev/testing purposes hence why these services are running concurrently.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Simon

Comment: Set the RRAS to use DHCP instead of static adress deployment. Additionally, in your DHCP range (create one if needed), add the correct  DNS-Server; the default filter on the VPN Interface would block the DNS traffic otherwise.